# Authentication on a smtp server fails using libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, smtp, libcurl

I try to send an email using the following code :

```
#include "optimnet_mail.h"
#include <cstring>

struct upload_status {
  int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp){
    char *data = static_cast<char*>(userp);
    if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
        return 0;
        }
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    return len;
    }

std::string mailText(const std::string destination, const std::string content){
    const std::string stringResult = 
        "To: " + destination + 
        "\r\nFrom: " + FROM +
        "\r\nSubject: Solver has finished\r\n" +
        "\r\n" + content + "\r\n";
    return stringResult;
    }

int sendMail(const std::string destination, const std::string content){

    const std::string text = mailText(destination, content);
    char *data = new char [text.length()+1];
    std::strcpy (data,text.c_str());

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
    struct upload_status upload_ctx;

    upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
    /* Set username and password */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, FROM);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, PASS);
    
    //using smtps fails instantly
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://" HOST ":" PORT);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);

    /* If your server doesn't have a valid certificate, then you can disable
    * part of the Transport Layer Security protection by setting the
    * CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST options to 0 (false).
    */
       //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
       //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "~/.ssh/known_hosts");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);

    // Add two recipients
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, destination.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

    //upload data
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    /* Send the message */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Free the list of recipients */
    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

    /* Always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    delete data;
    return (int)res;
    }

int main(){
    return sendMail(std::string("myemail@mycompany.com"),std::string("Test2"));
    }
```

Unfortunately, executing this code gives me the following log :

```
*   Trying 83.166.143.44:465...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mail.infomaniak.ch (83.166.143.44) port 465 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=mail.infomaniak.ch
*  start date: Feb 17 22:44:47 2021 GMT
*  expire date: May 18 22:44:47 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mail.infomaniak.ch" matched cert's "mail.infomaniak.ch"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
< 220 mail.infomaniak.com ESMTP ready
> EHLO conway
< 250-mail.infomaniak.com
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE
< 250-ETRN
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-DSN
< 250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
> AUTH PLAIN
< 334 
> Some hash
< 535 5.7.0 Invalid login or password
* Closing connection 0
curl_easy_perform() failed: Login denied
```

On the other hand, when using this curl command :
`curl --ssl-reqd --url 'smtps://mail.infomaniak.ch' --user 'user@example.com:password' --mail-from 'user@example.com' --mail-rcpt 'myemail@mycompany.com' --upload-file mail.txt`, the email is indeed sent.

Is there something I missed in my code? I don't understand why using the exact same login and password would make the authentication fail.

Edit : thanks to rustyx and Sam Varshavchik, I corrected a problem of port and a problem of memory leak.

Comment: 587 is a smtp port, smtps port is 465.

Comment: I see several potential source of bugs. `payload_source` fails to check for buffer overflows. It completely ignores the size of the buffer it receives. If it gets only a 1 byte buffer it will happily overwrite it with as much data as it can find. Additionally, I don't see anywhere where authentication credentials are actually set. A Google search for examples of using SMTP authentication finds plenty of examples using certain settings that don't appear anywhere in the shown code. Finally, there's also a memory leak. `data` is never `delete`d.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your answer. I understand your point on `playload_source`, yet, this part is never touched by the code for now as the authentication fail above. What do you mean by set authentication credentials? This code is actually from the [libcurl examples](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html) and I don't see anything as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there is a difference between the host, that looks like `<myemail@mycompany.com>` and the user, that looks like `myemail@mycompany.com`. This is what was causing authentication failure.